# How to track conversions to install ios app used Google Ads?

Tags: xcode, firebase

I want to use Google Ads to promote my Ios app. After setting up the company, I was given a message indicating that I need to set up a conversion to install.

I have already installed the Firebase SDK in my xcode project. Now I need to understand where and what exactly to configure on the Firebase site. P.S Working with Firebase and Google Ads for the first time, so maybe something is not so understand as it is in reality. I would be grateful for a detailed guide on how to set everything up properly.

Comment: Don't repost the same problem multiple times please. At best it will get closed, but it may actually get you banned from the site. Instead, edit your original question (that I linked) to address the feedback that was given there.